# Plot multiple curves with qwt

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I want to do a few things that look like this picture with qwt.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcHMe.png)

Several curves in a plot and with each curve that can overflow on the other curves. My only idea is to put several broods in a plot and apply offsets. But this idea is difficult to maintain I find.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but we can't write full qwt tutorial here.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Using a single QwtPlot with multiples curves or another option ?

Comment: Yes, idea is to attach multiple plot curves to one plot.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yes, but this idea implies that each curve must be offset. And involves many other things (calculating average values to center values for example). Have you done this kind of thing in a projet ? I'm trying to analyse the edf browser code to understand how they plot the curves.

Comment: No plot chart class can ever figure how on concrete use case it is best to visualise data for specialists of particular domain. And I've done it enough to know that each domain of knowledge has somewhat different expectations. So if it is again something special then we have our QwtPointSeriesData, and we alter the samples in it exactly like needed. It is not rocket science ... I bet you can do it under an hour.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks for all your answers. Just one last question, for this plot I need to put text legend and a rectangle of color facing of all curves. So, I have the idea to set AxisScaleDiv and AxisScaleDraw. I'm overriding the drawLabel function to draw my rectangle and my text. Have you a smarter idea to do that ?

Comment: Depend what axis you talk about. About left and/or right axis ... those are usually needed as heavily custom. On worst cases may need to draw stuff yourself there. Keep those up to date and in sync with scaling of data shown with your program logic and null all smart features like "autoscaling". Top and/or bottom axis are usually opposite, those are typically in sync for all plots shown and features of library are typically sufficient (or even overabundant) for those.

Comment: @ÖöTiib It's on left axis.

Comment: I don't know ... in subdir "examples" you will find the example "legends". If it suits you use, if not extend it or draw yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In Qwt, you can assign a curve to either the left or right axis. When you need to visualize more than two curves stacked on top of each other, you have to use offsets. You could also try to subclass the QwtScaleDraw class.